# Is there a neater way for AutoMapper to convert from null to empty GUID than an explicit CreateMap?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have several non-nullable GUID properties in my Code First data model that map to `Guid?` in my view models. I have no use for the empty GUID (all zeroes), so I use the following mappings, but I can't help wondering if there is a neater way of doing this? The uncharted depths of AutoMapper configuration would take me years to explore all on my own.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Guid, Guid?>().ConvertUsing(guid => guid == Guid.Empty ? (Guid?)null : guid);
Mapper.CreateMap<Guid?, Guid>().ConvertUsing(guid => !guid.HasValue ? Guid.Empty : guid.Value);
```

Comment: Create a custom type converter. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters

Comment: My lambda expressions are essentially 'implicit' type converter functions. The above code is only called once per ASP.NET request, so they apply to all Guid/Nullable<Guid> mappings.

Comment: Not sure what "neater" would be then.

Comment: @DerekBeattie Not sure there is a 'neater' way, but this problem pattern includes most nullables based on value types.

Comment: @DerekBeattie Why not use your original comment as an answer. I think it is acceptable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom type converter.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters

```
 public class NullableByteToNullableIntConverter : ITypeConverter<Byte?, Int32?>
    {
        public Int32? Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return context.IsSourceValueNull ? (int?) null : System.Convert.ToInt32(context.SourceValue);
        }
    }
```

Then:

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<byte?, int?>().ConvertUsing<NullableByteToNullableIntConverter>();
```